# Ubuntu 18.04 lags and mouse doesn't respond for a few seconds

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning

recently I formatted my computer and installed Windows 10. Next I installed Ubuntu 18.04. While using Ubuntu I wanted to power off. This screen appeared and I still can see it.

[image]

I also can see similar screens (for a second), but with much less text sometimes while starting the computer.

**Update**:

I don't experience a black screen with text now, but a few times after starting the computer it lags, and I can't move the mouse for a few seconds. I don't know what the problem is. I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 with 50GB / (root) 70GB for /home and 32GB for swap because I have 32GB RAM.

```
przem@przem-X510UNR:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'   
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)   
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. UHD Graphics 620   
Kernel driver in use: i915   
Kernel modules: i915 -- 01:00.0   
3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150] (rev a1)   
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GP108M [GeForce MX150]   
Kernel driver in use: nouveau   
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau –
```

Comment: I actually can't, becouse i did not post 10 comments yet.

Comment: oh, i see. Ok. But you could edit your question and supply an working link! without, your question is not answerable

Comment: ok, now it's working

Comment: You need to install Nvidia drivers. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: przem@przem-X510UNR:~$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
 Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. UHD Graphics 620
 Kernel driver in use: i915
 Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150] (rev a1)
 Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GP108M [GeForce MX150]
 Kernel driver in use: nouveau
 Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau

Comment: I dont experience black screen with text now, but few times after launching computer, i have lags, i cant move mouse for few seconds, i dont know what is the problem also, i installed ubuntu next to win10 with 50gb / (root) 70gb for /home and 32gb for swap becouse i have 32gb ram

Comment: Hi, now it takes 2;13 minutes to start ubuntu, i dont know what is wrong but windows starts in few seconds.

Comment: I have problem with long booting time.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1210861/it-take-213-minutes-to-start-ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You killed Ubuntu's performance by creating a 32GB swap partition. New installations of Ubuntu 17.04 and later create a swap file by default instead of a swap partition. My computer has 32 GB RAM and it usually uses about 1-2 GB of swap maximum. I don't know why you think you need a separate `/home` partition either. A separate `/home` partition is a waste of valuable disk space on the SSD if your computer has an SSD.

If your files take up a lot of disk space, you need somewhere to store them, but it doesn't have to be a separate `/home` partition. It can be on another drive, on a data partition or wherever it is most convenient to store the files, and leave your `/home` folder on the root partition for files that you want to be stored in the `/home` folder. That way you won't run out of space on the root partition.

At this point I think it would be most convenient to reinstall Ubuntu 18.04 with only one partition. It would also be possible to resize the root partition by adding disk space from the unneeded partitions, but you haven't put much on Ubuntu yet, so reinstalling Ubuntu would be a quicker and easier way of doing it.