# It take 2:13 minutes to start ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 and created only one partition (root). It takes more then 2 min to start the system.I've read similar post however, don't understand how can I deliver you required info about the problem.

```
przem@przem-X510UNR:~$ systemd-analyze blame
         22.383s plymouth-quit-wait.service
         15.690s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
         12.661s apt-daily.service
          3.637s apt-daily-upgrade.service
          2.884s dev-sdb5.device
          2.493s snapd.service
          2.429s systemd-logind.service
          2.385s gpu-manager.service
           794ms fwupd.service
           605ms systemd-journal-flush.service
           496ms dev-loop1.device
           490ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-127.mount
           478ms dev-loop2.device
           469ms snap-core-8592.mount
           449ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-67.mount
           448ms dev-loop0.device
           400ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-406.mount
           400ms dev-loop3.device
           381ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1440.mount
           356ms snap-core-7270.mount
           351ms dev-loop4.device
           336ms snap-core18-1066.mount
           314ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-116.mount
           313ms dev-loop5.device
           303ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-544.mount
           301ms dev-loop6.device
           301ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-296.mount
           276ms dev-loop7.device
           266ms dev-loop10.device
           261ms dev-loop8.device
           261ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-81.mount
           259ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1313.mount
           255ms systemd-udevd.service
           254ms dev-loop9.device
           227ms dev-loop12.device
           226ms dev-loop11.device
           211ms networkd-dispatcher.service
           196ms udisks2.service
           195ms dev-loop14.device
           190ms dev-loop13.device
           190ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           189ms systemd-resolved.service
           183ms NetworkManager.service
           169ms snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-100.mount
           160ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-61.mount
           145ms dev-loop15.device
           144ms ModemManager.service
           139ms grub-common.service
           130ms accounts-daemon.service
           125ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
           113ms snap-core18-1668.mount
           105ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-399.mount
           103ms thermald.service
            94ms systemd-rfkill.service
            79ms polkit.service
            65ms apparmor.service
            64ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-44ED\x2d1F02.service
            61ms keyboard-setup.service
            58ms motd-news.service
            54ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
            53ms systemd-journald.service
            53ms upower.service
            49ms plymouth-start.service
            46ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
            43ms apport.service
            39ms user@1000.service
            36ms packagekit.service
            32ms wpa_supplicant.service
            32ms bolt.service
            30ms networking.service
            30ms systemd-sysctl.service
            29ms snapd.seeded.service
            26ms systemd-modules-load.service
            24ms systemd-remount-fs.service
            23ms avahi-daemon.service
            22ms systemd-backlight@leds:asus::kbd_backlight.service
            21ms rsyslog.service
            20ms bluetooth.service
            16ms snapd.socket
            16ms binfmt-support.service
            15ms ureadahead-stop.service
            15ms alsa-restore.service
            14ms gdm.service
            13ms colord.service
            12ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
            11ms plymouth-read-write.service
            11ms speech-dispatcher.service
            10ms systemd-random-seed.service
            10ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
             9ms kerneloops.service
             8ms boot-efi.mount
             7ms pppd-dns.service
             7ms dev-mqueue.mount
             6ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
             6ms dns-clean.service
             6ms dev-hugepages.mount
             6ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
             4ms kmod-static-nodes.service
             4ms console-setup.service
             4ms ufw.service
             4ms systemd-update-utmp.service
             3ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
             3ms systemd-user-sessions.service
             3ms rtkit-daemon.service
             2ms sys-kernel-config.mount
             2ms setvtrgb.service
             2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
```

**Edit 1**:

Now it takes 1:37 to start Ubuntu. I disabled NetworkManager-wait-online.service and apt-daily.service

```
         20.763s plymouth-quit-wait.service
          1.767s dev-sdb5.device
           728ms snapd.service
           604ms systemd-journal-flush.service
           545ms dev-loop1.device
           504ms dev-loop2.device
           503ms fwupd.service
           499ms dev-loop3.device
           490ms snap-core-8592.mount
           450ms dev-loop4.device
           441ms snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-406.mount
           441ms mnt-6414FEB114FE8578.mount
           430ms snap-core18-1668.mount
           397ms snap-core-7270.mount
           389ms dev-loop0.device
           386ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-116.mount
           382ms systemd-timesyncd.service
           381ms systemd-resolved.service
           371ms snap-core18-1066.mount
           369ms snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-399.mount
           369ms snap-gnome\x2dlogs-81.mount
           368ms dev-loop5.device
           360ms dev-loop7.device
```

```
Startup finished in 6.108s (firmware) + 3.270s (loader) + 2.803s (kernel) + 3min 508ms (userspace) = 3min 12.691s
graphical.target reached after 1min 51.236s in userspace
```

```
graphical.target @1min 51.236s
└─multi-user.target @1min 51.236s
  └─snapd.seeded.service @1min 31.034s +19ms
    └─snapd.service @1min 30.305s +728ms
      └─basic.target @1min 30.265s
        └─sockets.target @1min 30.265s
          └─snapd.socket @1min 30.265s +568us
            └─sysinit.target @1min 30.258s
              └─systemd-timesyncd.service @2.079s +382ms
                └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @2.062s +13ms
                  └─local-fs.target @2.061s
                    └─run-user-1000-gvfs.mount @1min 34.326s
                      └─run-user-1000.mount @1min 30.627s
                        └─local-fs-pre.target @314ms
                          └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service @262ms+51ms
                            └─kmod-static-nodes.service @257ms +4ms
                              └─systemd-journald.socket @250ms
                                └─system.slice @250ms
                                  └─-.slice @248ms
```

**Edit 2**:

Can i delete these snaps? What are the consequences of deleting them?

```
/etc/systemd/system$ systemctl list-unit-files | grep snap
snap-core-7270.mount                                             enabled        
snap-core-8592.mount                                             enabled        
snap-core18-1066.mount                                           enabled        
snap-core18-1668.mount                                           enabled        
snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-116.mount                          enabled        
snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-67.mount                           enabled        
snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-406.mount                               enabled        
snap-gnome\x2dcalculator-544.mount                               enabled        
snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-296.mount                               enabled        
snap-gnome\x2dcharacters-399.mount                               enabled        
snap-gnome\x2dlogs-61.mount                                      enabled        
snap-gnome\x2dlogs-81.mount                                      enabled        
snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-100.mount                        enabled        
snap-gnome\x2dsystem\x2dmonitor-127.mount                        enabled        
snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1313.mount                          enabled        
snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1440.mount                          enabled        
snapd.autoimport.service                                         enabled        
snapd.core-fixup.service                                         enabled        
snapd.failure.service                                            static         
snapd.seeded.service                                             enabled        
snapd.service                                                    enabled        
snapd.snap-repair.service                                        static         
snapd.system-shutdown.service                                    enabled        
snapd.socket                                                     enabled        
snapd.snap-repair.timer                                          enabled
```

Comment: Please run `systemd-analyze blame` and [edit] your question to include the output of that command.

Comment: Some of your issues are addressed here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/958838/ubuntu-16-04-3-still-takes-1-5-minutes-to-boot-after-successful-clone-to-ssd-a/958850#958850

Comment: Some more: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2417453&p=13857392#post13857392 & 
https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/ubuntu-beaver-slow-boot.html
I also remove all snaps, and only use .debs. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2436900&p=13932499#post13932499

Comment: Thanks for that links i will check them in my free time ;) then i will report if anything change

Comment: How can I remove snaps and what is the consequence of doing it?